# How to customize the code which servers datarbicks models

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

I'm researching how to align databricks model deployments with our company's current rules and best-practices. They don't include any information on how the server of a deployment can be customized: [databricks model serving how-to](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/create-manage-serving-endpoints.html).

Contextual information, in case it matters:

- we'll use aws for infrastructure
- with "customizing the server" I mean how to e.g. instrument it with open-telemetry, or make it serve openapi-pages